# Why does adding a smallint column to a postgres query increase execution time 60X?

Tags: postgresql

Here I have what seems to me to be a routine table and a table creation script that I have put in /tmp/try.sql.  I am running postgres under OSX 10.10.2.

Here is the table:

```
cow_dev=# \d carc
                                Table "public.carc"
    Column     |     Type     |                         Modifiers
---------------+--------------+---------------------------------------------------   ---------
 internal_id   | integer      | not null default nextval('carc_internal_id_seq'::regclass)
 acct_nbr      | character(6) |
 birth_date    | date         |
 anm_key       | integer      |
 slghtr_dt     | date         |
 sire_assoc_id | integer      |
 sire_reg      | text         |
 dam_assoc_id  | integer      |
 dam_reg       | text         |
 sex           | text         |
 carc_kphf_pct | real         |
 carc_wt       | integer      |
 marbling      | integer      |
 ribeye_area   | real         |
 usda_qlty_grd | smallint     |
 act_fat_thick | real         |
 carcass_group | text         |
 maturity      | integer      |
Indexes:
    "idx_a649568319866892fcdd3742289e8294" PRIMARY KEY, btree (internal_id)
    "idx_d4659e9f750ff68c75e11e89a950e386" btree (anm_key)
    "idx_d57025002b9ce54cf590b76e87c10cac" btree (acct_nbr)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "carc_acct_nbr__acct_acct_nbr_fk" FOREIGN KEY (acct_nbr) REFERENCES acct(acct_nbr)
    "carc_anm_key__anm_anm_key_fk" FOREIGN KEY (anm_key) REFERENCES anm(anm_key)
```

Here is the script:

```
create temp table carc_out as
     with assoc_map as 
     (select
         a.assoc_id,
         c.code_3 || a.brd_cd_id mb_name
      from
         assoc a
         join country_code c on c.code_2 = a.country_code_2)
     select
        c.internal_id,
        n.mb_assoc_reg anm_nbr,
        c.act_fat_thick,
        c.carc_kphf_pct,
        c.carcass_group,
        c.carc_wt,
        null::float carc_yld,
        c.marbling,
        c.maturity,
        c.ribeye_area,
        to_char(c.slghtr_dt, 'mmddyyyy') slghtr_dt,
        c.usda_qlty_grd
from
        carc c
        left join z2_raa_numbers n using (anm_key)
        left join assoc_map da on da.assoc_id = coalesce(c.dam_assoc_id, 1) 
        left join assoc_map sa on sa.assoc_id = coalesce(c.sire_assoc_id, 1);
drop table carc_out;
```

Here are the results of running it twice, the first with the c.usda_qlty_grd not included in the query and the second with it included.

```
> time psql -U cow_peer -d cow_dev -c '\i /tmp/try.sql'
SELECT 25332
DROP TABLE

real    0m3.041s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.004s
10:57:46 521 0 tom@angus-2 ~
> time psql -U cow_peer -d cow_dev -c '\i /tmp/try.sql'
SELECT 25332
DROP TABLE

real    3m1.958s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.004s
```

As you can see, it takes 3 seconds one time and 3 minutes the other.  This is repeatable and is at least somewhat independent of what additional column you add to the query.  Interestingly the user and sys times don't seem to change.  The execution plans are identical. I am perplexed.

Here is the query plan without the column:

```
 QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Hash Left Join  (cost=1220.51..122913.55 rows=25332 width=54) (actual time=48.925..3254.720 rows=25332 loops=1)
   Output: c.internal_id, n.mb_assoc_reg, c.act_fat_thick, c.carc_kphf_pct, c.carcass_group, c.carc_wt, NULL::double precision, c.marbling, c.maturity, c.ribeye_area, to_char((c.slghtr_dt)::timestamp with time zone, 'mmddyyyy'::text)
   Hash Cond: (COALESCE(c.sire_assoc_id, 1) = sa.assoc_id)
   CTE assoc_map
     ->  Hash Join  (cost=7.54..10.16 rows=52 width=11) (actual time=0.271..0.392 rows=52 loops=1)
           Output: a.assoc_id, ((c_1.code_3)::text || (a.brd_cd_id)::text)
           Hash Cond: (a.country_code_2 = c_1.code_2)
           ->  Seq Scan on public.assoc a  (cost=0.00..1.52 rows=52 width=10) (actual time=0.003..0.012 rows=52 loops=1)
                 Output: a.assoc_id, a.assoc_code, a.priority, a.csu_priority, a.mb_priority, a.description, a.country_code_2, a.brd_cd_id
           ->  Hash  (cost=4.46..4.46 rows=246 width=7) (actual time=0.250..0.250 rows=246 loops=1)
                 Output: c_1.code_3, c_1.code_2
                 Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 10kB
                 ->  Seq Scan on public.country_code c_1  (cost=0.00..4.46 rows=246 width=7) (actual time=0.004..0.114 rows=246 loops=1)
                       Output: c_1.code_3, c_1.code_2
   ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=1208.66..122614.19 rows=25332 width=58) (actual time=48.867..3220.637 rows=25332 loops=1)
         Output: c.internal_id, c.act_fat_thick, c.carc_kphf_pct, c.carcass_group, c.carc_wt, c.marbling, c.maturity, c.ribeye_area, c.slghtr_dt, c.sire_assoc_id, n.mb_assoc_reg
         Hash Cond: (COALESCE(c.dam_assoc_id, 1) = da.assoc_id)
         ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=1206.97..122451.64 rows=25332 width=62) (actual time=48.380..3204.285 rows=25332 loops=1)
               Output: c.internal_id, c.act_fat_thick, c.carc_kphf_pct, c.carcass_group, c.carc_wt, c.marbling, c.maturity, c.ribeye_area, c.slghtr_dt, c.dam_assoc_id, c.sire_assoc_id, n.mb_assoc_reg
               Hash Cond: (n.anm_key = c.anm_key)
               ->  Seq Scan on public.z2_raa_numbers n  (cost=0.00..61034.69 rows=3330869 width=19) (actual time=0.057..937.277 rows=3330869 loops=1)
                     Output: n.mb_assoc_reg, n.anm_key
               ->  Hash  (cost=642.32..642.32 rows=25332 width=51) (actual time=46.444..46.444 rows=25332 loops=1)
                     Output: c.internal_id, c.act_fat_thick, c.carc_kphf_pct, c.carcass_group, c.carc_wt, c.marbling, c.maturity, c.ribeye_area, c.slghtr_dt, c.anm_key, c.dam_assoc_id, c.sire_assoc_id
                     Buckets: 2048  Batches: 128 (originally 4)  Memory Usage: 1025kB
                     ->  Seq Scan on public.carc c  (cost=0.00..642.32 rows=25332 width=51) (actual time=0.007..18.372 rows=25332 loops=1)
                           Output: c.internal_id, c.act_fat_thick, c.carc_kphf_pct, c.carcass_group, c.carc_wt, c.marbling, c.maturity, c.ribeye_area, c.slghtr_dt, c.anm_key, c.dam_assoc_id, c.sire_assoc_id
         ->  Hash  (cost=1.04..1.04 rows=52 width=4) (actual time=0.461..0.461 rows=52 loops=1)
               Output: da.assoc_id
               Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 2kB
               ->  CTE Scan on assoc_map da  (cost=0.00..1.04 rows=52 width=4) (actual time=0.275..0.436 rows=52 loops=1)
                     Output: da.assoc_id
   ->  Hash  (cost=1.04..1.04 rows=52 width=4) (actual time=0.042..0.042 rows=52 loops=1)
         Output: sa.assoc_id
         Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 2kB
         ->  CTE Scan on assoc_map sa  (cost=0.00..1.04 rows=52 width=4) (actual time=0.001..0.018 rows=52 loops=1)
               Output: sa.assoc_id
 Total runtime: 3256.486 ms
(38 rows)
```

Here is the query plan with the column:

```
QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Hash Left Join  (cost=1220.51..122913.55 rows=25332 width=56) (actual time=11588.296..179838.116 rows=25332 loops=1)
   Output: c.internal_id, n.mb_assoc_reg, c.act_fat_thick, c.carc_kphf_pct, c.carcass_group, c.carc_wt, NULL::double precision, c.marbling, c.maturity, c.ribeye_area, to_char((c.slghtr_dt)::timestamp with time zone, 'mmddyyyy'::text), c.usda_qlty_grd
   Hash Cond: (COALESCE(c.sire_assoc_id, 1) = sa.assoc_id)
   CTE assoc_map
     ->  Hash Join  (cost=7.54..10.16 rows=52 width=11) (actual time=0.211..0.314 rows=52 loops=1)
           Output: a.assoc_id, ((c_1.code_3)::text || (a.brd_cd_id)::text)
           Hash Cond: (a.country_code_2 = c_1.code_2)
           ->  Seq Scan on public.assoc a  (cost=0.00..1.52 rows=52 width=10) (actual time=0.002..0.015 rows=52 loops=1)
                 Output: a.assoc_id, a.assoc_code, a.priority, a.csu_priority, a.mb_priority, a.description, a.country_code_2, a.brd_cd_id
           ->  Hash  (cost=4.46..4.46 rows=246 width=7) (actual time=0.186..0.186 rows=246 loops=1)
                 Output: c_1.code_3, c_1.code_2
                 Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 10kB
                 ->  Seq Scan on public.country_code c_1  (cost=0.00..4.46 rows=246 width=7) (actual time=0.003..0.065 rows=246 loops=1)
                       Output: c_1.code_3, c_1.code_2
   ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=1208.66..122614.19 rows=25332 width=60) (actual time=11588.203..179739.516 rows=25332 loops=1)
         Output: c.internal_id, c.act_fat_thick, c.carc_kphf_pct, c.carcass_group, c.carc_wt, c.marbling, c.maturity, c.ribeye_area, c.slghtr_dt, c.usda_qlty_grd, c.sire_assoc_id, n.mb_assoc_reg
         Hash Cond: (COALESCE(c.dam_assoc_id, 1) = da.assoc_id)
         ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=1206.97..122451.64 rows=25332 width=64) (actual time=11587.812..179701.171 rows=25332 loops=1)
               Output: c.internal_id, c.act_fat_thick, c.carc_kphf_pct, c.carcass_group, c.carc_wt, c.marbling, c.maturity, c.ribeye_area, c.slghtr_dt, c.usda_qlty_grd, c.dam_assoc_id, c.sire_assoc_id, n.mb_assoc_reg
               Hash Cond: (n.anm_key = c.anm_key)
               ->  Seq Scan on public.z2_raa_numbers n  (cost=0.00..61034.69 rows=3330869 width=19) (actual time=0.170..1052.251 rows=3330869 loops=1)
                     Output: n.mb_assoc_reg, n.anm_key
               ->  Hash  (cost=642.32..642.32 rows=25332 width=53) (actual time=96.305..96.305 rows=25332 loops=1)
                     Output: c.internal_id, c.act_fat_thick, c.carc_kphf_pct, c.carcass_group, c.carc_wt, c.marbling, c.maturity, c.ribeye_area, c.slghtr_dt, c.usda_qlty_grd, c.anm_key, c.dam_assoc_id, c.sire_assoc_id
                     Buckets: 2048  Batches: 65536 (originally 4)  Memory Usage: 1028kB
                     ->  Seq Scan on public.carc c  (cost=0.00..642.32 rows=25332 width=53) (actual time=0.007..15.858 rows=25332 loops=1)
                           Output: c.internal_id, c.act_fat_thick, c.carc_kphf_pct, c.carcass_group, c.carc_wt, c.marbling, c.maturity, c.ribeye_area, c.slghtr_dt, c.usda_qlty_grd, c.anm_key, c.dam_assoc_id, c.sire_assoc_id
         ->  Hash  (cost=1.04..1.04 rows=52 width=4) (actual time=0.371..0.371 rows=52 loops=1)
               Output: da.assoc_id
               Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 2kB
               ->  CTE Scan on assoc_map da  (cost=0.00..1.04 rows=52 width=4) (actual time=0.214..0.354 rows=52 loops=1)
                     Output: da.assoc_id
   ->  Hash  (cost=1.04..1.04 rows=52 width=4) (actual time=0.045..0.045 rows=52 loops=1)
         Output: sa.assoc_id
         Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 2kB
         ->  CTE Scan on assoc_map sa  (cost=0.00..1.04 rows=52 width=4) (actual time=0.001..0.018 rows=52 loops=1)
               Output: sa.assoc_id
 Total runtime: 179844.270 ms
(38 rows)
```

Comment: This is really strange. It's only the `hash right join` that takes so much longer. I wonder if the number of columns exceeds some threshold that causes this. You probably should post that to the Postgres performance mailing list.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name also the hashing that precedes that join has an enormous amount of batches.  It seems that `work_mem` is very limiting in the second case - no idea why (if the tuple width estimation if the planner is correct).

Comment: Looks like a bug in the hash batches calculation.  What version of PostgreSQL, including minor point release, are you running?

Comment: cow_dev=# select version();
                                                                              version
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.3.5 on x86_64-apple-darwin, compiled by i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.9.00), 64-bit
(1 row)

Comment: You should at least upgrade to the latest point release of your major version, which is currently 9.3.10. Details: http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/ And check if that makes the problem go away.

Comment: hash join estimation was pretty thoroughly redone in 9.5.0.  Can you upgrade to that and see if the problem still exists?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: You need a sightly larger `work_mem`. Try `set work_mem` in your session.

Explanation:

Compare these two step:

```
           ->  Hash  (cost=642.32..642.32 rows=25332 width=51) (actual time=46.444..46.444 rows=25332 loops=1)
                 Output: c.internal_id, c.act_fat_thick, c.carc_kphf_pct, c.carcass_group, c.carc_wt, c.marbling, c.maturity, c.ribeye_area, c.slghtr_dt, c.anm_key, c.dam_assoc_id, c.sire_assoc_id
                 Buckets: 2048  Batches: 128 (originally 4)  Memory Usage: 1025kB
                 ->  Seq Scan on public.carc c  (cost=0.00..642.32 rows=25332 width=51) (actual time=0.007..18.372 rows=25332 loops=1)
                       Output: c.internal_id, c.act_fat_thick, c.carc_kphf_pct, c.carcass_group, c.carc_wt, c.marbling, c.maturity, c.ribeye_area, c.slghtr_dt, c.anm_key, c.dam_assoc_id, c.sire_assoc_id
```

and

```
           ->  Hash  (cost=642.32..642.32 rows=25332 width=53) (actual time=96.305..96.305 rows=25332 loops=1)
                 Output: c.internal_id, c.act_fat_thick, c.carc_kphf_pct, c.carcass_group, c.carc_wt, c.marbling, c.maturity, c.ribeye_area, c.slghtr_dt, c.usda_qlty_grd, c.anm_key, c.dam_assoc_id, c.sire_assoc_id
                 Buckets: 2048  Batches: 65536 (originally 4)  Memory Usage: 1028kB
                 ->  Seq Scan on public.carc c  (cost=0.00..642.32 rows=25332 width=53) (actual time=0.007..15.858 rows=25332 loops=1)
                       Output: c.internal_id, c.act_fat_thick, c.carc_kphf_pct, c.carcass_group, c.carc_wt, c.marbling, c.maturity, c.ribeye_area, c.slghtr_dt, c.usda_qlty_grd, c.anm_key, c.dam_assoc_id, c.sire_assoc_id
```

You see the slower query use 65536 batches, the faster one use 128.
This is because with the extra field, the batch can't fit in work_mem.. it need to split to smaller batches.

Comment: This hash is only slightly slower than the fast one (well, about double the time, but it's only 50 ms).  The real difference shows itself in the Hash Right Join node - also, one smallint in the 10+ column list cannot cause such a big change, in my view.

Comment: @dezso  The Hash Right Join node must operate on the number of batches set up for it by the Hash node.  So where the problem manifests is one place, but where the problem is caused is the other place.  Also, while I agree that adding one smallint column **should** not cause this particular change, I think the evidence speaks for itself.

Comment: @dezso yes, but the large batch number shows they don't fit in memory (and have written to temp files). Retrieving them from disk for hash join step is slow. Why not give it a try and see? 
Changing `work_mem` is trivial -- it is a session configurable.

Comment: If you want a solid proof, do an `explain (analyze,buffers)` and you will see what i am saying.

Comment: @J-16SDiZ  Unfortunately we can't try it out for ourselves, as we don't have access to the OP's data.  This is a data-dependent problem.